# Downloading key ratios for various Tickers with python library FundamenalAnalysis

Tags: python, list, loops, download, finance

I try to download key financial ratios from yahoo finance via the FundamentalAnalysis library. It's pretty easy for single I have a df with tickers and names:

```
  Ticker                      Company
0      A    Agilent Technologies Inc.
1     AA            ALCOA CORPORATION
2    AAC             AAC Holdings Inc
3    AAL  AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC
4   AAME      Atlantic American Corp.
```

I then tried to use a for-loop to download the ratios for every ticker with fa.ratios().

```
for i in range (3):
    i = 0
    i = i + 1
    Ratios = fa.ratios(tickers["Ticker"][i])
```

So basically it shall download all ratios for one ticker and the second and so on. I also tried to change the df into a list, but it didn't work as well. If I put them in a list manually like:

```
Symbol = ["TSLA" , "AAPL" , "MSFT"]
```

it works somehow. But as I want to work with Data from 1000+ Tickers I don't want to type all of them manually into a list. 
Maybe this question has already been answered elsewhere, in that case sorry, but I've not been able to find a thread that helps me. Any ideas?

Comment: why do you use `i = 0` inside `for i` ? This way you always have the same value in `i`. You should use `print()` to see what you have in variables - ie. `print(i, tickers["Ticker"][i])`

Comment: can't you get `Symbol = tickers["Ticker"].to_list()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get symbols using

```
symbols = df['Ticker'].to_list()
```

and then you could use `for`-loop without `range()`

```
ratios = dict()

for s in symbols:
    ratios[s] = fa.ratios(s)

print(ratios)
```

Because some symbols may not give ratios so you should use `try/except`

---

Minimal working example. I use `io.StringIO` only to simulate file.

```
import FundamentalAnalysis as fa
import pandas as pd
import io

text='''Ticker                      Company
A    Agilent Technologies Inc.
AA            ALCOA CORPORATION
AAC             AAC Holdings Inc
AAL  AMERICAN AIRLINES GROUP INC
AAME      Atlantic American Corp.'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}')

symbols = df['Ticker'].to_list()
#symbols = ["TSLA" , "AAPL" , "MSFT"]
print(symbols)

ratios = dict()
for s in symbols:
    try:
        ratios[s] = fa.ratios(s)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(s, ex)

for s, ratio in ratios.items():
    print(s, ratio)
```

---

**EDIT:** it seems `fa.ratios()` returns `DataFrames` and if you will keep them on list then you can concatenate all `DataFrames` to one `DataFrame`

```
ratios = list()  # list instead of dictionary
for s in symbols:
    try:
        ratios.append(fa.ratios(s))  # append to list
    except Exception as ex:
        print(s, ex)

df = pd.concat(ratios, axis=1)  # convert list of DataFrames to one DataFrame

print(df.columns)
print(df)
```

Doc: [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: I tried to use your working example. it works fine. I get a dict with 4 dfs. One Ticker has changed so it was skipped. if it's okay for you I would have 2 more questions: How can I transform my df full of tickers to the text =```Ticker... ```Format you used? And second, as I´m not very familiar with dicts, how do I transform the dict to a dataframe? I tried using: ``` pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ratios)``` Online it says that the keys in the dict would be taken as index, but it returns I have to pass an index..? Sorry for the follow-up-

Comment: I used `text =Ticker...` only to simulate file with data so everyone can easily copy it and run it without having real file with data. You should read data from file `read_csv(filename)`.  And I simply copied data from your question and formated it manually. If you use `print(df)` you should see similar result on screen. Eventually you may have to set some options to display long lines or many rows without `...`

Comment: I found method to convert `ratios` to `DataFrame` - I added code to answer.